# Why is this question on hold? How can I stop it being on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold

So I asked my first ever question on Stack overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968299/how-to-move-a-css-and-javascript-image-carousel-around-a-static-image

Within minutes I'd been told three times I'd asked the question wrong and now it's on hold. In my opinion the question couldn't be much clearer and all my code is in there, so how can I ever get an answer?

Comment: Ahhh, ok, I see now, thanks for making that clear to me.
I'll see what I can do about rephrasing my question and I'll try again.

Comment: You might also want to refer to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/) might also help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You failed to state an actual problem.

What do you need help with there? What did you struggle with?

You cannot just dump a load of code and say 'I want an image in there now'. That's asking everyone else to do the work for you, that's not how Stack Overflow works. You'd hire a specialist instead.

You can improve the question by editing it; state what you tried and how that didn't work. In other words, give us your input, your effort, so we have a starting point to see where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

### put on hold as unclear what you're asking

Read your question, you failed to ask the actual problem you were facing. Which part of your code didn't work as expected.